# Magento Connect manager : Connection Error try again later

Tags: magento

(I have been reading all related question and non of them fix my issue, basicaly they are different issue.)

I am new to magento, however I have some experience with php.

I recently installed magento on a shared server. The installation went ok, but, I can't install extensions through Magento Connect Manager. Every time I put in the url:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_Locale_pt_BR

I get in the console:

POST http://www.(mydomain)/downloader/index.php?A=connectPreparePackagePost
403 Forbidden
        499ms

Html response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /downloader/index.php
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

As an extra information, I have to say that I haven't done any configuration so this is a fresh installation of magento, that I just wanted to put in portuguese.

I tried to change /downloader/index.php to 0777 and 0755, but still the same thing.

Magento 1.9.1.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get new key for download package pt_BR. Following is new key http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Locale_Mage_community_pt_BR

This is in beta version so you need to change connect manager -> setting-> version beta then save setting and try to install.

Comment: I tried, what you said, but it still exact the same error.

Comment: Download extension and copy folder in your magento

Comment: how could I download an extension? This url won't download. :(